# Report Builder Multiple Group Matrix Calculation

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I have a Matrix created using Matrix Wizard in Report Builder 3.0(2014), having 2 row groups ,1 column groups and 2 values. After I create the matrix (included total and subtotal), I have a matrix that look just nice. But now I want to add one more cell for each columns groups (one row), to store the below value.

Value = Total of 1st row group + Total of 2nd row group - Total of 3rd row group ...

The matrix built just show me the subtotal of each row group which I don't need.

I want to ask how do I retrieve the result of total calculated by matrix itself and how do I identify them based on their row group value using expression? And also, how do I do this for every column groups which have different data?

I tried to look at the expression in design view of the matrix, it just shows [SUM(MyField)] for every cell in the Matrix (total & subtotal).

Or should I do it at another dataset using another query? If so, what query should I use and how do I put two dataset into one matrix?

My Matrix looks something like this :

```
                                              Column Group
ROW GROUP 1  | ROW GROUP 2           | VALUE 1         | VALUE 2
Row Group 1  | Row Group 2           | [Sum(MyField)]  | [Sum(MyField)]
             | TOTAL OF ROW GROUP 1  | [Value]         | [Value]
             | ROW PLAN TO ADD       | [Value(0)+Value | [Value(0)+Value
                                     | (1)-Value(2)]   | (1)-Value(2)]
```

CAPITALS    : Column name, constant

[sqrbrkted] : Calculated Value

Normal      : data inside table

I am new to Report Builder, sorry if I made any mistake. In case I didn't make myself clear, please do comment and let me know. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I have figured out an approach to achieve my purpose at the answer section below. If anyone have other solution, please feel free to answer it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing my SQL query to make another dummy column which shows negative result if its respective row group is meant to deduct the subtotal (Value(2)), and place it inside the matrix. And inside the expression, I have another IIF statement to convert it back to positive for display purpose.

SQL:

```
SELECT *, (CASE WHEN COL_B = 'VAL_2' THEN -COL_A ELSE COL_A END)AS DMY_COL_A FROM TABLE
```

Expression:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!DMY_COL_A.Value)<0,-Sum(Fields!DMY_COL_A.Value),Sum(Fields!DMY_COL_A.Value))
```